# Will undervolting with Intel XTU on Windows, be applied on Ubuntu aswell?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cpu, overheating, undervolting

Recently I undervolted my laptop CPU on Windows with Intel XTU due to overheating. I use dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. I am not particularly aware how and on what level the undervolting takes place.

I wanted to know if all the same voltage has been applied throughout my system, linux included.

Answer (score 6):

When rebooting from Windows to Linux, the settings will persist.

When cold booting to Linux, defaults will be used.

CPU voltage parameters are volatile and reset on shutdown.

Under Ubuntu you can use [undervolt](https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt). It's not as powerful as ThrottleStop or XTU, but it gets the job done for me.